# absolute min date

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-2.0

For political correctness, I would like to know if there is a way to instantiate a date so that it contains the lowest date value possible in c# net v2.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try DateTime.MinValue.  This is the lowest possible value for a DateTime instance in the CLR.  It is a language independent value.

Comment: thanks, exactly what I wanted. no way records could possibly have been created before time itself :)

Comment: You'll find most value types have similar, useful static properties like this.

Answer (score 7):

A newly constructed DateTime object also handily constructs by default to MinValue.

Answer (score 3):

DateTime myDate = DateTime.MinValue;